# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_connect_errno() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I received the following error on my localhost:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_connect_errno()
> expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given in

Using:
XAMPP v3.2.4, both Apache and MySQL running on correct ports (they are active). It is giving an error on line 52, which is the `if` statement below.

**Code:**

```
public function __construct()
     {
        $db = $this->localDatabase();
        
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['db']);
        
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->con))
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Like the error explains. mysqli_connect_errno() expects exactly 0 arguments you are giving it one. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php

Comment: Simply remove the `$this->con` from your call to `mysqli_connect_errno($this->con)`, The error could not be clearer.

Comment: Thank you. However other issues came up. Perhaps I need to downgrade the PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `mysqli_connect_errno` does not take any parameters (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php), the purpose of this function is to:

> Returns the last error code number from the last call to
> mysqli_connect().

If you are looking to determine if the connection successfuly established then you should do the following:

```
public function __construct()
     {
        $db = $this->localDatabase();
        
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['db']);
        
        if (!$this->con)
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }
```

You can see an example on php.net (under Example #1): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: THank you RJK. Your answer helped me to atleast fix the issue which I provided here. It did not fix the whole soluation because new errors came up. But I downgraded to lower PHP version (it was PHP 8, now it is 7.3, this fixed everything :-p)

Answer (score 1):

The function `mysqli_connect_errno` doesn't take any arguments as can be seen in the documentation.

**You really should not be using this function!** Please, forget that it even exists. Instead enable proper mysqli error reporting and stop worrying about manual error checking.

The correct way to open a connection with mysqli is this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$this->con = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], $db['db']);
$this->con->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Nothing more!